# Как правильно пересоздать закэшированный Observable используемый вместе с Retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rxjava, rxandroid

**Дано:**

API, возвращающее список с данными в формате `JSON`.

**Задача:**

Получить эти данные силами `Retrofit`+`RxJava`.

**Проблема:**

Необходимо сделать изначально один запрос и не дублировать его, если экран будет повёрнут до окончания задачи. Также нужно иметь возможность перезапустить задачу.

**Что получилось:**

Первое я решил, сделав Singlton и закешировав единственный экземпляр `Observable` с помощью `cache()`.

Второе - полным пересозданием объекта `Retrofit` (1), экземпляра retrofit-интерфейса (2) и самого `Observable`(3). Если 1 и 2 не сделать - 3 - остаётся прежним и возвращает закэшированные данные, вместо новых.

**Вопрос:**

Использованный мной способ перезапуска задачи получения данных выглядит плохо. Как лучше/правильнее пересоздать `Observable`?

---

Синглтон для получения/пересоздания `Observalbe`:

```
public class SingltonRetrofit
{
    private static RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxAdapter = RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io());

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Const.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
            .build();

    private static GetModels apiService = retrofit.create(GetModels.class);
    private static Observable<ArrayList<Model>> observableModelsList;

    public static void reset()
    {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Const.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
                .build();
        apiService = retrofit.create(GetModels.class);
        observableModelsList = null;
    }

    public static Observable<ArrayList<Model>> getModelsObservable()
    {
        if (observableModelsList == null)
        {
            observableModelsList = apiService.getModelsList().cache();
        }
        return observableModelsList;
    }
}
```

**P.S.**

Этот же вопрос на английском: [How to recreate or reset cached Observable, used with Retrofit to get new data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38173653/how-to-recreate-or-reset-cached-observable-used-with-retrofit-to-get-new-data)

Comment: Попробуйте реализовать BehaviorSubject. Подписываться (в onResume) и отписываться (в onPause) на него в Activity, а он будет подписан на Retrofit. При принудительном refresh'е обновлять подписку у Subject'а на retrofit (видимо). Кодом не помогу, проверять негде. Про subject'ы здесь неплохо написано https://habrahabr.ru/post/270023/

Comment: `observableModelsList = apiService.getModelsList().cache()` - таким образом кэшируется запрос.
А если поместить в метод reset() лишь пересоздание observableModelsList
`public static void reset()
    {
        observableModelsList = apiService.getModelsList();
    }`
такое не срабатывает?

Comment: @YuraIvanov, спасибо за наводку на BehaviorSubject - он пригодился в итоге) Правда подписывать его напрямую у меня не вышло - он в случае получения `onComplete` транслирует его как последний полученный элемент своим подписчикам и это всё портит) На счёт когда подписываться - как я понял в `onPause` и `onResume` это лучше делать чтоб не получить вылет при попытке манипулировать с UI после открепления фрагмента, например?

Comment: @mit, да, вы правы - `cache()` всё портило) Правда я так и не нашёл нигде упоминаний о том, что оно кэширует сетевой запрос, а не только данные, транслируемые `Observable` - откуда вы это знаете? Правда просто пересоздание `Observable` в `reset()` не помогло бы, т.к. мне ещё надо иметь возможность получать последние данные, если они были получены. Решил через связку `Observable` с `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: Попробуйте связку RxJava + Retrofit + Moxy, логика получается крайне легкой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В итоге сделал так:

1. Как верно написал @mit, метод `cache()` кэшировал запрос и пересоздание observable в итоге не перезапускало сетевой запрос. При этом в доках и в интернетах я нигде сему упоминания не находил. Видать это как-то связано с внутренней логикой связки Retrofit+OkHttp
2. При этом как верно предложил @Yura Ivanov, потребовался `BehaviorSubject`.
   На него подписывается фрагмент и его же можно пересоздать в случае нужды в свежих данных (без пересоздания будет отданы последние данные). При этом при каждом создании/пересоздании `BehaviorSubject` создаётся `Subscriber` для получения данных из сети через Observable, создаваемый Retrofit-ом. И он в `onError` и в `onNext` вызывает соответствующие методы у `BehaviorSubject`. При этом не транслируя `onComplete`, т.к. в этом случае может произойти ситуация, когда данные придут в процессе пересоздания фрагмента и фрагмент получит только последнее событие `BehaviorSubject`, т.е. событие завершения последовательности, вместо последних полученных данных. Т.е. соединять подпиской напрямую `BehaviorSubject` и `Observable`, получающий сетевые данные не стоит.
   Итого все требования соблюдены: При поворотах экрана будет запущена всего однажды задача на скачивание данных, фрагмент получит данные (или сообщение об ошибке) в любом случае и пересоздавать объекты Retrofita-а не нужно.

Итоговый синглтон:

```
public class SingltonRetrofitNew
{
    private static RxJavaCallAdapterFactory rxAdapter = RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io());

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    private static Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Const.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
            .build();

    private static GetModels apiService = retrofit.create(GetModels.class);

    private static BehaviorSubject<ArrayList<Model>> observableModelsList;
    private static Observable<ArrayList<Model>> observable = apiService.getModelsList();
    private static Subscription subscription;

    private SingltonRetrofitNew()
    {
    }

    public static void resetObservable()
    {
        observableModelsList = BehaviorSubject.create();

        if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed())
        {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
        subscription = observable.subscribe(new Subscriber<ArrayList<Model>>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted()
            {
                //do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e)
            {
                observableModelsList.onError(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ArrayList<Model> hotels)
            {
                observableModelsList.onNext(hotels);
            }
        });
    }


    public static Observable<ArrayList<Model>> getModelsObservable()
    {
        if (observableModelsList == null)
        {
            resetObservable();
        }
        return observableModelsList;
    }
}
```

Сокращённый фрагмент:

```
public class FragmentsList extends Fragment
{
    private static final String TAG = FragmentList.class.getSimpleName();
    private Subscription subscription;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRef;
    private ArrayList<Hotel> models = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean isLoading;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        //init views
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        swipeRef = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_ref);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh()
            {
                 SingltonRetrofitNew.reset();
                 getModelsList();
            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            models = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(Const.KEY_MODELS);
            isLoading = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(Const.KEY_IS_LOADING);
        }

        if (models.size() == 0 || isLoading)
        {
            getModelsList();
        }
        //TODO show saved data if is

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed())
        {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }

    private void getModelsList()
    {
        isLoading = true;
        swipeRef.setRefreshing(true);
        if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed())
        {
            subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
        subscription = SingltonRetrofitNew.getModelsObservable().
                subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
                observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                subscribe(new Subscriber<ArrayList<Hotel>>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted()
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onError", e);
                        isLoading = false;
                        swipeRef.setRefreshing(false);
                        Snackbar.make(recyclerView, R.string.connection_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .setAction(R.string.try_again, new View.OnClickListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v)
                                    {
                                        SingltonRetrofitNew.reset();
                                        getModelsList();
                                    }
                                })
                                .show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ArrayList<Hotel> newModels)
                    {
                        isLoading = false;
                        swipeRef.setRefreshing(false);
                        models.clear();
                        models.addAll(newModels);
                        //TODO show data
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList(Const.KEY_MODELS, models);
        outState.putBoolean(Const.KEY_IS_LOADING, isLoading);
    }
}
```

Всё вместе на gitHub: [RxRetrofitAndScreenOrientation](https://github.com/mohaxspb/RxRetrofitAndScreenOrientation)

Статья на ХабраХабр про решение: [Используем RxJava и Retrofit на Android, учитывая поворот экрана](https://habrahabr.ru/post/305478/)

Comment: Круто +1. Осталось добавить логику принудительного рефреша (pullToRefresh например) и класс будет иметь завершенный вид. А потом сделать все это же самое без rx и сравнить количество кода :)

Comment: @YuraIvanov, спасибо) Тут сначала не стал приводить код с принудительным рефрешем, чтоб код не засорять, но вот сейчас добавил - через SwipeRefreshLayout, хоть его и не поправили нормально у гугла до сих пор... А без Rx, пожалуй, таки подлиннее будет и менее интересно чем так))

Comment: Ну, могу сказать за себя, rx не очень жалую, у нас в связке с volley пропадают подписки, дебажить это дело практически не реально, ветвление алгоритма, жизненный цикл, все это запутывает код неимоверно. Кроме того, при росте количества видов запросов, объем кэшируемых данных, хранящихся в таких же синглтонах не оправдывает себя. И есть ощущение, что rx должен быть уровнем выше, т.е. на уровне запусков активити из друг друга, тогда это будет реально функциональный подход, а так... баловство, имхо.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, я сам в бою rx не использовал, как и volley, засим ничего про потери ч-л сказать не могу. Просто оно сейчас на слуху, да и в вакансиях часто поминают, вот и решил палкой потыкать этого зверя) Мне лично понравилось - свежо и заставила попотеть непривычная концепция) А вот что вы имели в виду под "уровнем выше" я не понял...

Comment: Ну что-то типа... жизненный цикл приложения - это некий функциональный поток состояний, в графе, подписавшись на которые можно генерить другие состояния, все это многопоточно... Это понятное дело, просто некая неразвитая мысль о мысли на тему функционального всего. Сейчас в любом случае реализация чего бы то ни было идет через колбэки, просто rx дает (и то не везде) некий не очевидный сахар, а количество кода и красота в итоге хороши только в примерах типа хеллоуворлд.

Comment: Юрий, я посмотрел сначала Вашу статью на хабре, испугался и понял, что для каждой задачи писать обертку в виде Rx'a — совсем не вариант. Сейчас пробую подход MVP + Moxy. По смыслу, так вообще не нужно заботиться о проблемах с пересозданием активности.

Comment: @RostislavDugin, статья - мой первый опыт использования rx и retrofita. Так что да - MVP если исползовать то статья не нужна и вообще плоха)

Answer (score 3):

Не претендую на лучшую реализацию, но...
Лично я у себя во избежания повторных запросов держу данные отдельно от любой активити, дабы не захламлять код.

Есть некий класс, который всегда создается в памяти при старте приложения 
к примеру пусть будет Model

```
public class Model {
    public final MyData mayData;

   public Model(RestApi mRestApi) { //мне удобно передовать сразу интерфейс апи
        mayData = new MyData(mRestApi);

   }
}
```

Старт его происходит в классе наследованного от Application.

Класс MyData - обычный класс в котором описаны запросы для конкретного экрана или типа данных.

```
    public class MyData {
    public MainPageInfo(RestApi retrofit) {
        super(retrofit);
    }

    public void getData() {
        mRestApi.getData().enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Data>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Data>> call, Response<ArrayList<Data>> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<Data>> call, Throwable t) {
                setError(t);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Для удобства доступа к модели я храню на нее ссылки в классах унаследованных от фрагмента или активити, в свою очередь их ставлю в наследники для нужных мне вью. Как итог - во время переворота дестроятся сама вьюшка, но не данные и их легко попросить у класса MyData с просто проверкой на null (делать запрос если данных нет). Конечно реализация не совершенна, как и здесь я описал не весь код (кроме всего есть модель слушателей)). Но я почему то думаю для вас это не проблема и вы сами решите подойдет вам этот метод или нет. Единственный недостаток - если дестроется все приложение, то и данные тоже. Зато можно обратиться к данным из любого места =), Если что пишите на почту ) расскажу подробней )

Comment: Как данная схема помогает не делать повторный запрос при повороте во время текущего запроса?

Comment: по простому в MyData храните последний ответ, десериализованный  JSON в виде объекта. Когда у вас сработает переворот экрана, у вас пересоздается только вьюшка и объекты, которые в инициализировали в классе вашего экрана (activity\fragment). На класс отнаследованый от Application, который переопределяется  для контроля старта приложения (если это конечно делаете), переворот не влияет. Как следствие Application класс остается не тронутым. В нем то и инициализирована та самая модель. Получая ссылку на модель и классы внутри нее вы получаете доступ к данным.

Comment: Для этого достаточно в onResume получить ссылку на модель, и спросить у нее ваши данные.

Comment: Вы не поняли. Запрос1->Переворот->Запрос2->Результат1+Результат2. Вот Запрос2 и Результат2 не нужны. Ваша схема подразумевает какую-то дополнительную обработку - проверять идет ли запрос, а что делать если данные не пришли по ошибке и т.д.

Comment: Да вы правы, если Сall позволял делать проверку isExecuted(), то с Observable уже не так прозрачно