# Retrofit 2 : Как получить response.body из UI-потока?

Tags: java, android, json, многопоточность, retrofit

**Дано:**

`RecyclerView` из элементов  `CardView`.
За `RecyclerView` отвечает `ManagerListAdapter`, в конструктор которого передаётся `ArrayList` при создании экземпляра. Элементы `ArrayList` заполняют `CardView` в `ManagerListAdapter.`

Это всё работает корректно.

**Задача:**

В конструктор `ManagerListAdapter` при создании его экземпляра передавать `ArrayList`, полученный с JSON с использованием Retrofit 2.

**Проблема:**

Как говорит гугл, в UI потоке нельзя создавать подобные GET-запросы, нужно использовать асинхронный поток через `.enuque`

При этом,
`ManagerListAdapter` можно создавать только в UI-потоке.

**Вопрос:**

Как корректно передать полученный  с JSON `ArrayList`  в конструктор адаптера `ManagerListAdapter`?

Быть может, я использую не совсем тот подход?

**Инициализация `RecyclerView` в одном из `Fragment`:**

```
private void initRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView managersRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.managersRecyclerView);
        managersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        managersRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ManagerListAdapter(getManagers()));




//        getRemoteManagers();


    }

private void getRemoteManagers() {

    ApiObject client = ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiObject.class);
    Call<List<ManagerDTO>> call = client.getManagers();


    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ManagerDTO>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<ManagerDTO>> call, Response<List<ManagerDTO>> response) {


            if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                List<ManagerDTO> managers = response.body(); //Эту коллекцию я хочу добавить в конструктор ManagerListAdapter
                sortManagers(managers);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<ManagerDTO>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


}


private List<ManagerDTO> getManagers() {

//Заглушка для тестирования, локальный вариант.

    List<ManagerDTO> managers = new ArrayList<>();

    managers.add(new ManagerDTO("Alex Pavlov", 100));
    managers.add(new ManagerDTO("Ivan Pavlov", 95));
    managers.add(new ManagerDTO("Petr Pavlov", 99));
    managers.add(new ManagerDTO("Stepan Pavlov", 100));
    managers.add(new ManagerDTO("Azik Pavlov", 100));
    managers.add(new ManagerDTO("Azik Myand", 100));
    managers.add(new ManagerDTO("Azik Specca", 50));
    managers.add(new ManagerDTO("Azik Kane", 0));
    managers.add(new ManagerDTO("Azik McDonald", 99));
    managers.add(new ManagerDTO("Azik Jagr", 1));

    sortManagers(managers);

    return managers;


}
```

**Этот вопрос так же задавал на англоязычном стеке:**

[How to get response from other thread using Retrofit 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390686/how-to-get-response-from-other-thread-using-retrofit-2-0)

---

**UPDATE 18.07**

**ServiceGenerator**

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    private static final String URL = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/";
    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
                    .baseUrl(URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create());


    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
```

**ApiObject**

```
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.http.GET;
import rx.Observable;





public interface ApiObject {

    @GET("11p73.json")
    Observable<List<ManagerDTO>> getManagers();

}
```

**getRemoteManagers**

```
private void getRemoteManagers() {

        ApiObject client = ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiObject.class);

        Observable<List<ManagerDTO>> managers = client.getManagers();
        managers
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<ManagerDTO>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {


                        //do nothing
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                        Log.e("OnError", "Not good");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<ManagerDTO> managers) {

                        RecyclerView managersRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.managersRecyclerView);
                        managersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                        managersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                        managersRecyclerView.setAdapter(new ManagerListAdapter(managers));
                    }
                });


    }
```

**Log:**

```
    07-18 06:29:43.706 4442-4442/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: ru.alexbykov.sailesstat, PID: 4442
                                                                       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lretrofit2/adapter/rxjava/RxJavaCallAdapterFactory;
                                                                           at ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.remote.dto.ServiceGenerator.<clinit>(ServiceGenerator.java:17)
                                                                           at ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.tabSales.ManagersFragment.getRemoteManagers(ManagersFragment.java:73)
                                                                           at ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.tabSales.ManagersFragment.initRecyclerView(ManagersFragment.java:67)
                                                                           at ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.tabSales.ManagersFragment.onCreateView(ManagersFragment.java:59)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android
07-18 06:29:43.706 4442-4442/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
07-18 06:29:43.706 4442-4442/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat D/Error: ERR: exMsg=Didn't find class "retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.3.0_5de1f4990c3728db7199bf5c90bfdb9def350a94-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-retrofit-2.1.0_8b8f8e10a24e9cbb87d2817f40dae9b260cf7282-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-okio-1.8.0_b8b5a990379e0c2ac791ab0c60e6d287203675f2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-okhttp-3.3.0_866858d020e75cefeef6ab6b91a11fd0f01f1cad-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-jackson-databind-2.7.2_16e021f670fa80a4e5bff4cbb34bd38f737d85f8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-jackson-core-2.7.2_dda0286f28d26c1864b8b07e760d8e17be822281-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-jackson-annotations-2.7.0_7ca878bfbcac373c0abd0f8db967beedc4f2d50f-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.3.0_7d4478fe63824ec180d999bac79eed2e00dfbdcd-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-converter-jackson-2.1.0_fb2f5790154a81f89b59fa9475c841489aa12048-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.jakewharton-butterknife-8.1.0_8235e6ed1a224a7cff79b1e0e63f739474e0008a-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-23.3.0_a8eb97e4d985983e20b47dc6def5331594cf0d7c-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.3.0_04c4d80e6e44a7b94ad5796f30419a8aafdc4608-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-recyclerview-v7-23.3.0_0274d8817f144b6caeef34836695e068a055782a-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-design-23.3.0_6836fcb43ed2de008a5ece0a6c80bfe80babf58c-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-cardview-v7-23.3.0_bb32e1ecd443ace6a7a6ef2db7a64f3647077cc0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-23.3.0_49ad66e001493b50a4c053b5bd9f87269fbc7ec1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-animated-vector-drawable-23.3.0_88f27537c1bceae88b9a0d4e5f96b37399657141-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat/files/instant-run/dex/slice-butterknife-annotations-8.1.0_ba06f0ea21d2a585450c9fb25457676f0e115968-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-18 06:29:43.706 4442-4442/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat D/Error: ERR: file=BaseDexClassLoader.java
07-18 06:29:43.706 4442-4442/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat D/Error: ERR: class=dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader
07-18 06:29:43.706 4442-4442/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat D/Error: ERR: method=findClass line=56
07-18 06:29:43.706 4442-4442/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lretrofit2/adapter/rxjava/RxJavaCallAdapterFactory;
                                                                  at ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.remote.dto.ServiceGenerator.<clinit>(ServiceGenerator.java:17)
                                                                  at ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.tabSales.ManagersFragment.getRemoteManagers(ManagersFragment.java:73)
                                                                  at ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.tabSales.ManagersFragment.initRecyclerView(ManagersFragment.java:67)
                                                                  at ru.alexbykov.sailesstat.statistic.fragments.tabSales.ManagersFragment.onCreateView(ManagersFragment.java:59)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.
07-18 06:29:43.706 4442-4442/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 36252
07-18 06:29:47.845 4442-4442/ru.alexbykov.sailesstat I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4442 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы выполнить что-то в UI потоке в активити у неё есть метод `runOnUiThread(Runnable run)`

Т.е. оберните нужный код так:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //код тут выполнится в основном потоке.
    }
});
```

---

Также можно приспособить сюда RxJava. Вот [вопрос с SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541099/17609), вот [репозиторий на GitHub](https://github.com/mohaxspb/RxRetrofitAndScreenOrientation) и [статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/305478/)

Comment: спасибо за очередной ответ и статьи, изучаю. (пока что сложно такой объём быстро понять).
По-поводу `runOnUiThread` - в условиях я сделал ошибку(уже исправил)., вместо `Activity` у меня крутятся `Fragment`'s.

Как я понял, можно так же решить данную проблему с помощью `Singleton` с нужным листом и  с `loadingIndicator`.

Comment: @nonews, если во фрагменте, то можно так: `getActivity().runOnUiThread(...);`

Comment: попробовал нужный участок кода обернуть (в моём примере это `initRecyclerView();`
Получил вот [такую](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout) 
 ошибку.

Comment: @nonews, это просто предупреждение в логах и всё работает или падает? Я лично не понял что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: приложение запускается, но при этом данные не подгружает, т.к. адаптер создался не в том потоке (если верить ссылке, указанной в прошлом комментарии).
Завтра по Вашему совету буду пробовать RxJava. Отпишусь о результатах

Comment: добавил RxJava. (Использовал часть Вашего примера с собственным `ServiceGenerator` ). 

Приложение крашится..ошибка в логах. Ругается на RxAdapter.

Comment: @nonews, скорее всего вы где-то что-то не так подключили в gradle. или версию чего-то в нём же не так указали.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42644/discussion-between-no-news-and-).